# Aurelia UX showcase app fails to load

Tags: aurelia

I'm having trouble getting the Aurelia UX Showcase app to run on my local PC. It doesn't currently seem to work on the [hosted demo](https://aux-demo.firebaseapp.com/introduction) site either, but I'm not sure if that's related. How can I get this running successfully? Is this a bug in the app, or something I'm doing wrong?

I followed the instructions to build the aurelia-ux demo app (located at https://github.com/aurelia/app-ux-showcase), and the app appeared to build succcessfully. However, upon running it, several errors are produced in the server output.

I can browse to the app (at http://localhost:8080) and the browser seems to connect to the server. However, there is no response.

Below is the server output, which is visible in the console after running the `au run --env dev` command:

```
C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase>au run --env dev
Starting 'configureEnvironment'...
Finished 'configureEnvironment'
Starting 'runWebpack'...
(node:14072) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
Project is running at http://localhost:8080
webpack output is served from /
Content not from webpack is served from C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\dist
404s will fallback to /index.html
Finished 'runWebpack'
Hash: 8541226efa5bac91e63a
Version: webpack 4.8.3
Time: 5594ms
Built at: 2018-05-22 13:15:17
                               Asset       Size   Chunks                    Chunk Names
2cdebc25fc6d3d42442e69826e81a2c9.png   10.5 KiB           [emitted]
                             main.js    701 KiB     main  [emitted]  [big]  main
                          vendors.js   3.88 MiB  vendors  [emitted]  [big]  vendors
                          index.html  743 bytes           [emitted]
Entrypoint main [big] = vendors.js main.js
[./node_modules/aurelia-bootstrapper/dist/native-modules/aurelia-bootstrapper.js] 5.17 KiB {vendors} [built]
[./node_modules/aurelia-loader-webpack/dist/native-modules/aurelia-loader-webpack.js] 14.4 KiB {vendors} [built]
[./node_modules/aurelia-loader/dist/native-modules/aurelia-loader.js] 4.19 KiB {vendors} [built]
[./node_modules/aurelia-logging/dist/native-modules/aurelia-logging.js] 3.4 KiB {vendors} [built]
[./node_modules/aurelia-pal/dist/native-modules/aurelia-pal.js] 2.18 KiB {vendors} [built]
[./node_modules/aurelia-polyfills/dist/native-modules/aurelia-polyfills.js] 24.4 KiB {vendors} [built]
[./node_modules/aurelia-templating/dist/native-modules/aurelia-templating.js] 145 KiB {vendors} [built]
[./node_modules/aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry.js] 585 bytes {vendors} [built]
[./node_modules/aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/pal-loader-entry.js] 1.56 KiB {vendors} [built]
[./node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.js] 175 KiB {vendors} [built]
[0] multi aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/pal-loader-entry aurelia-bootstrapper 52 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/process/browser.js] 5.29 KiB {vendors} [built]
[aurelia-framework] ./node_modules/aurelia-framework/dist/native-modules/aurelia-framework.js 13.8 KiB {vendors} [built]
[aurelia-pal-browser] ./node_modules/aurelia-pal-browser/dist/native-modules/aurelia-pal-browser.js 14.2 KiB {vendors} [built]
[main] ./src/main.ts 966 bytes {main} [built]
    + 172 hidden modules

ERROR in ./node_modules/@aurelia-ux/components/dist/native-modules/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@aurelia-ux/button' in 'C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\@aurelia-ux\components\dist\native-modules'
 @ ./node_modules/@aurelia-ux/components/dist/native-modules/index.js 2:0-51 2:0-51 15:0-75 30:4-28
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ ./node_modules/aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry.js
 @ multi aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/pal-loader-entry aurelia-bootstrapper

ERROR in ./node_modules/@aurelia-ux/components/dist/native-modules/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@aurelia-ux/checkbox' in 'C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\@aurelia-ux\components\dist\native-modules'
 @ ./node_modules/@aurelia-ux/components/dist/native-modules/index.js 3:0-67 3:0-67 3:0-67 17:0-79 32:4-30
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ ./node_modules/aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry.js
 @ multi aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/pal-loader-entry aurelia-bootstrapper

ERROR in ./node_modules/@aurelia-ux/components/dist/native-modules/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@aurelia-ux/chip-input' in 'C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\@aurelia-ux\components\dist\native-modules'
 @ ./node_modules/@aurelia-ux/components/dist/native-modules/index.js 4:0-83 4:0-83 4:0-83 4:0-83 18:0-77 33:4-26
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ ./node_modules/aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry.js
 @ multi aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/pal-loader-entry aurelia-bootstrapper

ERROR in ./node_modules/@aurelia-ux/components/dist/native-modules/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@aurelia-ux/datepicker' in 'C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\@aurelia-ux\components\dist\native-modules'
 @ ./node_modules/@aurelia-ux/components/dist/native-modules/index.js 6:0-59 6:0-59 19:0-83 34:4-32
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ ./node_modules/aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry.js
 @ multi aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/pal-loader-entry aurelia-bootstrapper

ERROR in ./node_modules/@aurelia-ux/components/dist/native-modules/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@aurelia-ux/form' in 'C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\@aurelia-ux\components\dist\native-modules'
 @ ./node_modules/@aurelia-ux/components/dist/native-modules/index.js 7:0-47 7:0-47 21:0-71 36:4-26
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ ./node_modules/aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry.js
 @ multi aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/pal-loader-entry aurelia-bootstrapper

ERROR in ./node_modules/@aurelia-ux/components/dist/native-modules/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@aurelia-ux/input' in 'C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\@aurelia-ux\components\dist\native-modules'
 @ ./node_modules/@aurelia-ux/components/dist/native-modules/index.js 8:0-58 8:0-58 8:0-58 22:0-73 37:4-27
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ ./node_modules/aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry.js
 @ multi aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/pal-loader-entry aurelia-bootstrapper

ERROR in ./node_modules/@aurelia-ux/components/dist/native-modules/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@aurelia-ux/input-info' in 'C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\@aurelia-ux\components\dist\native-modules'
 @ ./node_modules/@aurelia-ux/components/dist/native-modules/index.js 9:0-58 9:0-58 23:0-82 38:4-31
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ ./node_modules/aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry.js
 @ multi aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/pal-loader-entry aurelia-bootstrapper

ERROR in ./node_modules/@aurelia-ux/components/dist/native-modules/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@aurelia-ux/list' in 'C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\@aurelia-ux\components\dist\native-modules'
 @ ./node_modules/@aurelia-ux/components/dist/native-modules/index.js 10:0-47 10:0-47 24:0-71 39:4-26
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ ./node_modules/aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry.js
 @ multi aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/pal-loader-entry aurelia-bootstrapper

ERROR in ./node_modules/@aurelia-ux/components/dist/native-modules/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@aurelia-ux/radio' in 'C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\@aurelia-ux\components\dist\native-modules'
 @ ./node_modules/@aurelia-ux/components/dist/native-modules/index.js 11:0-58 11:0-58 11:0-58 25:0-73 40:4-27
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ ./node_modules/aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry.js
 @ multi aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/pal-loader-entry aurelia-bootstrapper

ERROR in ./node_modules/@aurelia-ux/components/dist/native-modules/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@aurelia-ux/switch' in 'C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\@aurelia-ux\components\dist\native-modules'
 @ ./node_modules/@aurelia-ux/components/dist/native-modules/index.js 13:0-61 13:0-61 13:0-61 27:0-75 42:4-28
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ ./node_modules/aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry.js
 @ multi aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/pal-loader-entry aurelia-bootstrapper

ERROR in ./node_modules/@aurelia-ux/components/dist/native-modules/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@aurelia-ux/textarea' in 'C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\@aurelia-ux\components\dist\native-modules'
 @ ./node_modules/@aurelia-ux/components/dist/native-modules/index.js 12:0-67 12:0-67 12:0-67 26:0-79 41:4-30
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ ./node_modules/aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry.js
 @ multi aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/pal-loader-entry aurelia-bootstrapper
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
         Asset      Size  Chunks  Chunk Names
    index.html  1.36 MiB       0
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./index.ejs] 1.1 KiB {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js] 527 KiB {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 519 bytes {0} [built]
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /vendors.js
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /main.js
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /
× ｢wdm｣: ConcurrentCompilationError: You ran Webpack twice. Each instance only supports a single concurrent compilation at a time.
    at Compiler.run (C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:151:37)
    at rebuild (C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\lib\context.js:81:24)
    at done (C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\lib\context.js:59:7)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:18:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:35:21)
    at emitRecords.err (C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:203:22)
    at Compiler.emitRecords (C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:315:39)
    at emitAssets.err (C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:197:10)
    at hooks.afterEmit.callAsync.err (C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:301:14)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:35:21)
    at asyncLib.forEach.err (C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:298:27)
    at done (C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2854:11)
    at C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2805:7
    at MemoryFileSystem.writeFile (C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\memory-fs\lib\MemoryFileSystem.js:328:9)
    at writeOut (C:\src\aurelia-ux-showcase\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:284:29)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the command to `au run --watch`.

It should run using the dev environment by default, and there is a known issue with Webpack and the Aurelia CLI at the moment after one of the recent Webpack updates when running the application without the `--watch` flag.

**Edit**

Also, try installing dependencies with Yarn, `npm install` does not seem to be installing the packages correctly at the moment, however `yarn install` seems to work fine.

`npm install yarn`

`yarn install`

Comment: Installing with `yarn` seemed to fix the problem. Thanks!